# Module not found on migration from 10 to 13 - nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I've recently tried to migrate our old site running on next 10 to the latest version 13. The site has a custom backend written with express. While running the project via concurrently I keep getting Module not found error as soon as I run the client on 3000. This is the scripts section("npm run dev" below is used to run the project):

```
"start_dev": "nodemon --inspect -w ./src/server -w ./src/server.js -w ./src/start.js ./src/start.js",
 "build": "next build",
 "client": "next dev",
 "server": "npm run build && npm run start_dev",
 "dev": "npx concurrently -k \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
```

[image]

Things seem to be working fine if I build the project first and then run client and server on separate terminals. But with this also, if I make a change in server that doesn't get picked up by client on the other terminal.

I'd highly appreciate if someone can give this a look as I'm stuck on the same issue for quite some time now. Please let me know if any further information is needed from my end here.

Comment: you need to create a minimal reproducible code base or share your source code. noone can solve this error without seeing the code

Comment: Not possible to answer without minimal reproducible example but try not using with experimental features first.

Comment: Have you tried updating to Next.js 11 then 12 first before doing 13? There might be other breaking changes around Webpack or the build process that are causing this

Comment: @Yilmaz Came up with a basic repo here, although not able to reproduce the error in the question but here also facing one challenge. When the server is up and running with "npm run dev" and if we make a change in the server, client blows up saying can't find some module. Please check this once on this repo: https://github.com/ATakaSKY/test-next13

Comment: @SheaHunterBelsky same problem is happening with next 12 as well

Answer (score 0):

the problem is if the `.next` folder is generated by `nodemon` change, client side webpack hot reload cannot read .next folder

```
"scripts": {
    "client": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "server": "npm run build && npm run nodemon",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "nodemon": "nodemon -w ./src/server.js -w ./src/server ./src/start.js",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

When you run `npm run dev` and refresh the page, this is how `.next/pages` folder. home `index.js` exists:

[image]

if I make a change in `./src/server.js` after I see the home page on screen, `.next` folder will be recreated without `index.js` by nodemon change and if I refresh the page I will get error.

[image]

when you reload your page after change in `server.js` file you get error because `index.js` page does not exist. It does not exist because `.next` folder was not generated by `webpack`

[image]

When you first start the app, before refreshing the browser, if you make a change on server.js file, `.next` folder will be created and if you refresh the page you will get the same error. for some reason if `.next` folder generated by the nodemon change, client side cannot communicate by `.next` folder.

`concurrently` runs scripts in parallel, with `npm run server` you are calling `next build` and with `npm run client` you are calling `next dev`. So, you are calling `next dev` and `next build` scripts concurrently. Even though it says it is concurrently, I think it is not exactly concurrently. if you install `npm i npm-run-all` and add this script

```
"dev": "npm-run-all --parallel client server"
```

your app will never load, you will see flickering in a loop.